# C# Json - extract a list of values from a JsonArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using this Json string (cannot be altered because I receive it from an external source)

```
{
  "IsValid": true,
  "Result": [
    {
      "PartNumber": "ABC",
      "Id": "x123"
    },
    {
      "PartNumber": "DEF",
      "Id": "y456"
    },
    {
      "PartNumber": "GHI",
      "Id": "z789"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need is a list of PartNumber/SupplyId like this one

```
"ABC", "x123"
"DEF", "y456"
"GHI", "z789"
```

I'm just doing it using a foreach approach, my question is: may I do it using something like

```
    var props = obj.Descendants() 
         .OfType<JProperty>() .Where(p => p.Name== "PartNumber" ||  p.Name == "SupplyId") 
... and now?
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access child tokens of `Result` array to get `PartNumber` and `Id` values, then map them to list of tuples or anonymous types using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var result = obj["Result"]?.Children()
    .Select(t => (t["PartNumber"]?.Value<string>(), t["Id"]?.Value<string>()))
    .ToList();
```

Or

```cs
var result = obj["Result"]?.Children()
    .Select(t => new { PartNumber = t["PartNumber"]?.Value<string>(), Id = t["Id"]?.Value<string>() })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly you can do something like this:

```
var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var result = jObj["Result"]
    .Children()
    .SelectMany(c => new[] { c["PartNumber"].ToString(), c["Id"].ToString()})
    .ToList()
```

`result` will contain flat list of part numbers and ids.